# What does this cookie line mean? (time()+1*24*60*60;)

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, httpcookie

I have a php code that says this time for the cookie to expire
What exactly does this mean?

```
time()+1*24*60*60;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what common thing do we all interact with every day that has 24 of something and that something has 60 of something and those 60 have another 60 of something? ;)

Comment: Basic math. current time() + 1(days) * 24(hours) * 60(minutes) * 60(seconds) = current time() + 86400 seconds

Comment: You mean two days?  @EgoistDeveloper

Comment: No, 1 day. You can think as current time() is zero or beginning. Plus depends to you. Your example expires after 1 day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted to in the comments - that's a calculation of seconds from the current time. That's 1 day (86400 seconds).

7 Days could be calculated similarly as:

```
time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
```

You can find a lot more explanation and examples in the PHP manual for the `time()` function - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: Thanks for the reply
But this // time () + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60; // It's been more than two days I tested but it has not been deleted yet

Comment: The browser will usually delete a cookie once it has expired. Check that the cookie has been set with the correct expiry date by using Chrome browser. On the relevant web page Right click and choose 'Inspect'. Go to the application tab and you'll be able to select Cookies for the relevant domain on the left hand side. Check what the browser is seeing your cookie as expiry date wise.